# Track number of devices per user

Tags: ios, iphone

Since the App Store on the iPhone allows you to download an app across multiple devices while paying only once, I need a way to keep track of the number of devices in addition to the number of people who purchased the app.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you only need a general number you could install any analytics system such as Flurry which will track all unique device installs and you can simply match that up with the download number in iTunes, which is going to be your actual purchases. Your unique device install number should be higher and however more there are is a general number of how many users have multiple devices. I say this is a general number though because it will not account for jailbroken installs and if people get new devices to replace existing and other conditions that would make your numbers less exact.

Comment: Would re-downloads on the same device count against the download number? (I do this all the time for larger games for instance.)

Comment: Usually not. Flurry and other analytics systems find ways to track unique devices. With the deprecation of the UDID there is a chance if you reinstalled the OS that they would loose it but I assume it wouldn't be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Not without jailbreaking, probably. Apple does not allow access to the Apple ID that purchased the app or even the UDID of the device. You could query for a username and password to do your own server-side authentication, using the MAC address or some variant of that to tie the account to the device.

But you'd need to run your own server and that wouldn't be tied to the Apple ID, unless you specifically ask for those credentials, and I don't think Apple allows apps that do that to be distributed through their store, except for in-app purchases. The API for in-app purchases does not give you access to credentials, either.